# Copy and paste for images in SharePoint

Tags: copy-and-paste, content-editor-web-part, publishing-page

It seems that whether it's a content editor web part or publishing page, copying and pasting images is a poor user experience in SharePoint. The user needs to upload the image somewhere first, then copy the path, then insert the image, hopefully paste the path in correctly, etc...

Is there any third party editor control that accepts pasted images and puts them somewhere sensible so the user doesn't have to be bothered with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theres some security issues here to consider as well.

Say we had the option to insert (and hence upload) images using copy/paste, where would these pictures reside? The fine grained security model of SharePoint give administrators the possibility to delegate security related tasks, such as being responsible for uploading corporate approved images.

In other words there would be no guarantee that the author/contributor had rights to store the images that was being pasted into the editor.

That being said, the way it works in normal SharePoint editor **is** a pain, and yes RAD editor makes up for some of that, but theres plenty of room for improvement :-)

Answer (score 1):

The the talk about security just doesn't jive with the fact that You can already do WYSIWYG editing of blog posts in Windows Live Writer and cut and paste images into that editor which are then uploaded to the blog site when you publish.  I see no reason this couldn't work with Wiki pages if Live Writer or another editor supported it.

Answer (score 0):

The publishing templates with the Site Collection Images selection is the only automated path I've seen.  No cut & paste options.  If there are any cut & paste solutions, I would be interested in where it actually put the files since I would rather that it be in a place the files can be managed to avoid a whole slew of other admin and security issues.

Comment: That's true, although it's a problem that could be solved. A good user experience is important or else they'll never use it in the first place. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I know of one Editor from [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/editor.aspx) which we have been using for sometime now and it does has an option to upload the Image from its window and paste. Though it is not supporting the Pasted Images, it does ease the User pain of uploading the Image in a Single window, they have two variations one a Free Lite Edition and Enterprise Edition $$. Nice comparison of the Features is there in the Site.

Comment: Yes I've used this. It's good but needing to think about uploading the images is a pain for users.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure security was the biggest driver on this as one could 'upload' a malicious image and cause issues.  Online images can still be referenced in any of the web parts/pages that allow for HTML editing by using the "<img src=http:// ...>" tag.